# setting mandatory field automatically in Rails from Model callback, when and how?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I have this model which has a mandatory field which needs to be automatically set just before save. I'm struggling with the correct way to implement this:

1. build the logic in the controller before the save (and have validates rule in model)
2. build the logic in a before_save callback and have validates rule in model, but this seems to late in the flow? I do get validation errors this way.
3. build the logic in a before_save callback and don't define validation for this particular field
4. do it any of the ways above and don't assign a validates rule for the particular field

I was working on 2 since this seems like the correct way to implement this. Was considering the usage of before_validation, but I don't know what would happen when my other fields don't get validated... this could cause double assignment of the same value..

code for 2 which gives a basic idea of what I'm trying to achieve:

```
#category.rb
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_create :set_position_number

  def set_position_number
    highest = Category.maximum(:position)
    self.position = highest.to_i + 1
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm struggling with the correct way to implement this

The most efficient way will be to use an [ActiveRecord callback](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html) hook, such as you've posted:

```
#app/models/category.rb
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
   before_create :your_action

   private

   def your_action
      #fires before create
   end
end
```

> but this seems to late in the flow

As mentioned in the comments, you can see the order of the callbacks (and thus their order in the flow):

[image]

Thus, if you want to populate some data *before* you validate, and then validate that data, you'll be best using the `before_validation` callback:

```
#app/models/category.rb
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
   before_validation :set_position_number, on: :create
   validates :position, ______________

   private

   def set_position_number
     highest = Category.maximum(:position)
     self.position = highest.to_i + 1
   end
end
```

Remember, a Rails model just populates certain attributes which are then to be either saved to the db, or validated. Rails does not care *where* those attributes come from; populating them `before_validation` is a good a source as the controller.

Comment: Thanks, so there's no risk of duplication of position number due to failed validations and resubmitting the data?

Comment: On update it will run as it does in create. You can however set a flag to only run on create (I've just amended my answer)

Comment: one last question... in the flow the 'valid' method seems to be called before the before_validation, which would allow me to check the invalidation from a Unit test, but valid? seems to be returning true even when I'm explicitly setting the position to nil, but my assert_not @category.valid? is not passing.

Answer (score 2):

If you are setting a value automatically and don't take user input, you don't need validation. Write a unit test.

If the field is something like a position value, then you should indeed set it in a before_create callback.

Comment: Also check http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html for which order the callbacks are run!

Comment: Ok, so it's common practice to completely skip validation rules for these kind of fields? It feels like something I would want to explicitly define in my model... any thoughts?

Comment: if it's automatically set, write a unit test or two to determine that it is, and move on with your life. Tests are to validate the machine and your code is doing its job, and validation is for user input. Validation shows messages in the ui, like, "This field is not set, please fix it." If the field is automatically set, the user can't modify it, so what use is a message if your code is broken and it didn't set it?